# Vagrant dhcp: get ip addresses

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Good day!
I want to up few nodes using dhcp. But I also want to get ip-addresses of this nodes and write them to file. Vagrant docs says "The IP address can be determined by using vagrant ssh to SSH into the machine and using the appropriate command line tool to find the IP, such as ifconfig".

So I created a simple bash script for master

```
`vagrant ssh master -c 'ifconfig | grep -oP "inet addr:\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | grep -oP "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1'`
```

and the same scripts for another nodes.

I want to put this scripts into Vagrantfile. What plugin should I use? I tries https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers.

```
config.trigger.after :up do
   ipAddr = `vagrant ssh master -c 'ifconfig | grep -oP "inet addr:\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | grep -oP "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1'`
   puts "master ipAddr #{ipAddr}"
   ipAddr = `vagrant ssh slave01 -c 'ifconfig | grep -oP "inet addr:\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | grep -oP "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1'`
   puts "slave01 ipAddr #{ipAddr}"
end
```

But it fires when one of the nodes is up, rather then both.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your approach to work on a multi-box setup with the [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin. Here's what worked for me:

```
# Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.define "test-web"
  config.vm.define "test-db"
  config.vm.define "test-dual"
  config.trigger.after :up, :stdout => false, :stderr => false do
    get_ip_address = %Q(vagrant ssh #{@machine.name} -c 'ifconfig | grep -oP "inet addr:\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | grep -oP "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1')
    @logger.debug "Running `#{get_ip_address}`"
    output = `#{get_ip_address}`
    @logger.debug "Output received:\n----\n#{output}\n----"
    puts "==> #{@machine.name}: Available on DHCP IP address #{output.strip}"
    @logger.debug "Finished running :after trigger"
  end  
end

# Console:
$ vagrant up test-web
Bringing machine 'test-web' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> test-web: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> test-web: Resuming suspended VM...
==> test-web: Booting VM...
==> test-web: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    test-web: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    test-web: SSH username: vagrant
    test-web: SSH auth method: private key
    test-web: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
==> test-web: Machine booted and ready!
==> test-web: Running triggers after up...
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
==> test-web: Available on DHCP IP address 172.28.128.3
```

Comment: Hi Chris, When I run the above code, I get the below error.
Do you have insights?

`code`
    vagrant validate
    Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

    There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
    and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
    an invalid or undefined variable.

    Path: /Users/Sunil/Vagrantfile
    Line number: 0
   Message: undefined method `name'

Comment: vagrant version
Installed Version: 2.1.5
Latest Version: 2.2.3

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/83743/chris-bloom