# Vagrant - Message: undefined method `name'

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am invoking the below Vagrant code to get the IP address. I am using DHCP to use a private network and allow the IP to be assigned via DHCP.

```
# Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.ssh.insert_key = true
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.define "test-web"
config.trigger.after :up, :stdout => false, :stderr => false do
get_ip_address = %Q(vagrant ssh #{@machine.name} -c 'ifconfig | grep -oP "inet addr:\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | grep -oP "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1')
@logger.debug "Running `#{get_ip_address}`"
output = `#{get_ip_address}`
@logger.debug "Output received:\n----\n#{output}\n----"
puts "==> #{@machine.name}: Available on DHCP IP address #{output.strip}"
@logger.debug "Finished running :after trigger"
end
end
```

When I validate the code, I get the below error? Looks like some issue with @machine.name.

```
vagrant validate
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded 
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by 
an invalid or undefined variable.

Path: /Users/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: undefined method `name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Vagrantfiles are Ruby programs. It would help if you, at least, indented it properly. As you suspected, there's an issue with @machine.name; the issue is that you haven't defined `@machine` anywhere. If you `puts @machine` it will probably show it's undefined. Looking at [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28835516/891440), which is apparently where you found it, it might be because the triggers plugin is not installed in your version.